# How can display a text and clear form when it was submitted in Kentico?

Tags: kentico

I need when a user submit a form this will be clear and display a text.
Hi, can it be possible? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the general settings for the Form you can do either Clear Form or Display Text, not both.

If you need both, I would suggest maybe redirecting to a URL, have the URL the same as the form, but with a querystring added, then on page load check for the querystring value and display the message if it exists. Otherwise you will have to edit the web part.

Keep in mind if you go the QueryString route, if they submit the form and get a validation error, your logic for displaying the message if the QueryString value exists will have to handle this, otherwise you are going to keep displaying it when it wasn't a success.

The easiest route would probably be just display a message with a link to reload the form.